# x386, Is there a way to PUSH using another register?

Tags: assembly

I mean when you do `PUSH 10`, it is similar to `DEC ESP; MOVE [ESP], 10`

but is there a way to do `DEC EDX; MOV [EDX], 10` in one command?
and same for other registers, EDX, EAX...

Comment: Nope, but as you already saw, you don't really need it that badly anyway - you only need two (fast) instructions to emulate it.

Comment: I consulted Intel x86 assmebly manual, and it seems there is only `PUSH` instruction that takes immediate byte and sign-extends it to 16 or 32 bits. No `PUSH` 8-bit immediate to stack as 8-bit variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std
mov EDI, offset ...
mov AL, 10
; Single instruction (save AL to ES:EDI, post-decrement of EDI)
stosb
```

Comment: You still need to repeat `mov AL, X; stosb` instructions. In fact, this answer results in 2 additional instructions.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit - Yes, only AL/AX/EAX can be stored that way and only `EDI` can be used as pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know, but you can use a macro:

```
PUSHEAX MACRO Value
DEC EAX
MOV [EAX], Value
ENDM
```

Or

```
PUSHREG MACRO Reg, Value
DEC Reg
MOV [Reg], Value
ENDM
```